# SQL Server - notify 1 month from time (SQL Agent)

Tags: sql, sql-server

im trying to right an SQL Query that will do the following task:

Example:

```
SellDate =        '2014-07-15'
ExpirationDate =  '2015-07-15'
TodaysDate =      '2015-06-15' --notify me by email
```

An item is sold, (SellDate) and is set to expire in 12 months (ExpirationDate)... 
 1 month before, I want SQL Server to email me informing that the item is about to expire based upon (TodaysDate)

so using the above 3 dates... could someone please give me some pointers as to where I go next... this is what I have tried so far.. the query below will find the item however I now want SQL Server Agent to send me an email for each row that is returned, not when nothing is returned

```
select * from Parts WHERE ExpirationDate = DATEADD(month, +1, '2015-06-15')
```

Comment: You should take a look at this article. http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/10/send-query-results-sql-server-agent-job/

Comment: ill have a read into it now... it explains well so hopefully I will be able to add in the part where it doesnt send the email if its blank

Comment: in the stored proc, do a raiseerror if rowcount =0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can create a simple HTML based on the items you need to return and then send the email

```
Declare @html Varchar(max)
SET @html = CAST(( SELECT ColName1 AS 'td','',ColName2 AS 'td','',
                  ColName3  AS 'td' ,''
FROM Parts 
WHERE Convert(date,ExpirationDate) = DATEADD(month, +1, getdate()) //Convert to date since not sure whether the datatype is date or datetime
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

Then you can inert this part (@html) in to proper format

And using [sp_send_dbmail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190307.aspx)

```
 IF(LEN(@html)>1)
 Begin
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                @recipients = @Emails , --add required emails here, use ; between email address if multiple
                @body_format = 'HTML',
                @importance = 'High',
                @body = @html,
                @subject = @subject -- add subject here
 End
```

Comment: im testing it now so will reply shortly, thankyou for your help

Comment: i think the getDate is getting the exact second, rather than the generic date... is there a way to limit this...

Comment: got it.. now to test:  DATEADD(month, +1, (SELECT CONVERT (date, GETDATE())))